# Centering the labels in circuits.logic.IEC

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

The tikz circuits library aligns the label for a gate to the top of the node, rather than to the center. Is there any way to move the label to the center?

I.e.: the black label for the not gate is drawn by tikz circuits library, and the red label is the position at which I would like tikz to draw the labels.

[image: not gate]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic IEC]
    \node (not) [not gate]{};
    \node[text=red] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `pgfmanual.pdf` page 554 you can use

[image]

It needs `shapes.gates.logic.IEC` library and only defines `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` alignments. But diving into code I could define a `center` alignment which worked for me with little examples. I don't know if something will break with it.

In any case, if you use this `center` alignment a possible `node's text` will overwrite it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.IEC}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/logic gate IEC symbol align/.cd,
  center/.code=\pgftransformyshift{0pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic IEC]
    \node (not) [logic gate IEC symbol align={center}, not gate, draw]{};
%    \node[text=red] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackish, but you could increase the inner separator for the not gate.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        ,circuit logic IEC
        ,not gate/.append style={inner sep=15}
        ]
    \node[text=red] {1};
    \node (not) [not gate]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]